# changed something to a system file, please help

Tags: themes, gtk

I messed arround with the colour values in the file : `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`

Can someone post the first line of that file? Or tell me what the original colours are? I would like to go back to the original :) (everything after "gtk-color-scheme = "untill "gtk-icon-sizes")

thanks in advance

edit: I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 13.10,

```
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#ffffff\nselected_bg_color:#f07746\nselected_fg_color:#FFFFFF\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\nbg_color:#f6f4f2\ntooltip_bg_color:#000000\nlink_color:#DD4814"

gtk-icon-sizes = "panel-menu=22,22:gtk-button=16,16"
```